# Display a Console in Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, console

I want to add a console to my application, and here's my problem.

In Qt Creator, I create a new Project, I select 'Qt Console Application', convert it from using `QCoreApplication` to `QApplication`, add `core` `gui` `widgets` to the `QT` configuration flag in the project file, and it works. I can create windows while having a console window. So the project file looks like this...

```
QT += core gui widgets

TARGET = ConsoleApp
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app

#sources...
```

This is working perfectly and I could develop a full GUI app with this; however, the app is already built. When I created the project for the app, I chose 'Qt Widgets Application'. So I thought I could just copy the configuration of the ConsoleApp's project file over to my app's project file. So My apps project file looks like this...

```
QT += core gui widgets

TARGET = GuiApp
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app

#sources...
```

But this is not showing me a console and I don't understand why.  I know I could just create a Console Application and just transfer my source over which right there solves my problem, but I wanna know... why is the console not showing up in my GUI app despite using the exact same configuration as the console app in the project file?

I'm compiling with Qt 5.3.1 MSVC2013 OpenGL 64bit on Windows 8 64bit, all in Qt Creator 3.1.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, GUI apps don't have the terminal enabled in QtCreator.  Enabling it is simple:

- In the left sidebar, click Projects
- At the top, select your project's Run tab
- In the Run section, check the Run in terminal checkbox

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it turns out the console only shows up when directly running the deployed executable, meaning actually navigating to it and running it manually, not by running it within Qt Creator. I should've tested this first before posting the question, but I really didn't think it would've done anything. I'll leave the question up because it might help some others out anyway.