# Enable console after openning qt project in visual studio

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012, console, visual-studio-addins

When I open a qt gui project in visual studio (through qt-addin and openning .pro file in vs), it does not open console for me while in .pro file I'd added this line :

```
CONFIG += console
```

and **console comes up in qt creator**, but my problem is when I open the pro file in visual studio!.

how can I open console inside my gui in visual studio after opening .pro file in it?  (I use qt5 and vs2012)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display a Console in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437639/display-a-console-in-qt)

Comment: You may set this option in project properties: `Linker->System`

Comment: @SaZ I've set that option but again nothing occurs! I've set subsystem to both  WINDOWS and CONSOLE but yet console doesn't appear in vs.

Comment: @Mezzo , my problem is that I cannot open console in visual studio, not in qt creator!!!

Answer (score 1):

After adding your new CONFIG line to the .pro file, run the following command line call in the MSVC command line window to regenerate your Visual Studio project to be one for a Qt console application:

> qmake -tp vc foo.pro

The Windows environment variables QMAKESPEC and QTDIR need to be properly set, and also set PATH=%QTDIR%\bin;%PATH%