# Force output in QtCreator for console app

Tags: c++, qt, console, output, qt-creator

When I am using Qt Creator to make a widget app, the text output is redirected to the Qt Creator built in console (For example from QDebug function). When I work with a console app however, the text output is redirected to a separate terminal window. How Can I decide where does the output go in Qt Creator? I would appreciate all help.

Comment: you will get help from below links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437639/display-a-console-in-qt
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171653/can-i-see-the-program-output-in-qt-creator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uncheck <kbd>[✓] Run in terminal</kbd> in your project options:

[image: helper screenshot]